# Vector Art Beginner Questions

Tags: vector

I recently left work to focus on my mental health. I’m doing this, I’ve found the only way I am able to quiet my mind and find relief is through art, which as become almost like meditation for me. I really want to get started doing vector art, but because I’m on disability I don’t have a lot of money to start. Can anyone suggest a possible laptop or tablet, and/or software programs to get started with? I basically just want to take pictures that make me feel good and simplify them to the point i can easily paint them without too much thought. I’m sorry I’m not familiar with all of the correct terms to use yet. I want to simplify the detailed shapes of things like facial features and layers of color rather than shading. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: We don't recommend hardware here. It's off-topic. Sorry about that. But almost any cheap Windows laptop will run Inkscape, which is a free and open source vector image editor.  It also works in Linux, so even Windows is not required. There are tons of tutorials on youtube for it too. Start with basic tutorials.

Comment: Krita (pixel based) is also fun to draw with. Any cheap laptop will do to start with. And wacom tablets to digitally draw with a pen are getting really affordable too. But even just a pencil and notebook goes a long way. I often just draw a scribble in my notebook see what it looks like and then make the line into a funny creature or something. – this way you never not know what to draw and always get surprised by some completely crazy outcome that you could never had come up with. I personally think analog drawing/painting helps me more with my mental issues. – Much love hope you get better!